# Trying to create a line chart with a linear x-axis, like the time axis, but with numerical data, in DimpleJS

Tags: d3.js, charts, linegraph, dimple.js

I have a line chart that I just noticed the x-axis is not linear.  I'm using AddAxis, and it's acting like a category axis.  This makes the scale on the x-axis non linear and spaces the points an equal distance apart.  I want the x scale to go from minimum x-value to maximum x-value and to be spaced equally based on the linear scale of min to max.  The time axis seems to do this, but I just have numerical data, not in a time format.

Is there another axis type I should be using? Or, is it possible to use the time axis and format the data to basic number and decimal values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use a measure axis like that.  Here's an example:

```
var data = [
  { "X Value" : 1000, "Y Value" : 100 },
  { "X Value" : 1500, "Y Value" : 200 },
  { "X Value" : 3000, "Y Value" : 400 },
  { "X Value" : 7000, "Y Value" : 100 },
  { "X Value" : 8000, "Y Value" : 200 },
  { "X Value" : 8500, "Y Value" : 100 },
];
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 400);
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
chart.addMeasureAxis("x", "X Value");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Y Value");
chart.addSeries("X Value", dimple.plot.line);
chart.draw();
```

http://jsbin.com/jugic/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks, that helps me realize what my actual problem is.  The data I have often looks like this http://jsbin.com/bexedo/1/edit so I guess my problem is more about setting the range of the xaxis to start at the minimum value and end at the max value.  There's a d3 function to do this, but will that work in Dimple?

Comment: awesome thanks, I was just playing with that.  Looks like I can use d3.max and d3.min to find the max and min values, then set your axis.overriteMin and Max to those values.  Thanks a bunch!